# Javascript Canvas how to remove a shape or area from an image?

Tags: javascript, canvas, electron

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with this but it doesn't seem to work. I want to remove a shape or symbol from an image by it's location, not by colour.

```
function crop(leftedge, topedge, wd, ht) {
  const imageData = context.getImageData(leftedge, topedge, wd, ht);
  const canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  canvas1.width = wd, canvas1.height = ht;

  ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

  ctx1.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  return canvas1;
}
```

For some reason the clearRect doesn't seem to do anything. Not sure what other way there is or if I'm doing this wrong. I tried `fillRect` as well but no result...the image is displayed with no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tha happens because the order of your operation matters. As it is right now, you're clearing that little 50 pixel square **before** you're overwriting it with new imageData.
Try this:

```
function crop(leftedge, topedge, wd, ht) {
  const imageData = context.getImageData(leftedge, topedge, wd, ht);
  const canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  canvas1.width = wd, canvas1.height = ht;

  ctx1.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

  return canvas1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that works, I never would have thought of that because I thought all the data had to be 'put' at the end after all processing.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's the little things causing us headaches. ;)